# Rotating image on mimic crop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to allow rotation on cropping an image (not a really cropping, I'm just using CSS to mimic). I'm using Jcrop to get the selected area and then I use one `div` that contains an image to mimic the cropping behavior (see code below).

However when the angle is 90 deg the image comes out of the box. I tried to use `max-height`, `max-width` and also `width`, `height` to `100%` but it's not working. I also tried to inverse width and height but still not working.

```
<div>
    <img src='img.jpg' id='original' />
</div>
<div id='content' style='overflow: hidden; position: relative;'>
    <img src='img.jpg' style='position: absolute;' id='crop'  />
</div>
<button id='rotate'>90deg</button>

<script>
    $('#rotate').click(function() {
        $('#crop').css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(90deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(90deg)'
        });
    });

    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#original').Jcrop({
            onSelect: showCoords
        });
    });

    function showCoords(c) {
        $('#content').css({
            'width':  c.w + 'px',
            'height': c.h + 'px'
        });

        $('#crop').css({
            'top':  '-' + c.y + 'px',
            'left': '-' + c.x + 'px'
         });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need a width/height assigned to #content for this to work. Right now it doesn't have one, so there are no bounds for hiding the overflow.

Comment: Sorry I inversed the height/width is for div#content and top/left for img#crop. I will try to edit edit

Comment: Check out the -moz-transform line of your JS - there's a single quote opening and double quote closing. Not sure if that's the issue or just a typo in bringing it here!

Comment: It's a typing error

Comment: Can you post a working example? I'm having a hard time recreating this with what's provided

Comment: I copy a working one from my code. The issue is with the rotating image which goes out the box

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116512/discussion-between-dramans-and-will).